# Run Chrome Extensions on Mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension  and it's running in the web browser in google chrome. I know that chrome extensions are not supported mobile chrome browser, but I want to find a way to run the same extension in mobile and chrome browser.

Based on this article [Run Chrome Apps on Mobile Using Apache Cordova](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile) we can run chrome apps on mobile using apache Cordova. But is any way to do the same thing for chrome extensions? 
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fully aware that there is no support for doing that, that's already answering your question.

There is nothing, as far as I know, that implements the full extension API on mobile. Do note that the point of extensions is to be deeply integrate with the browser and alter its behavior - so if Chrome doesn't support it, there's no point in further discussion.

However, for the sake of the argument, Chrome Apps. A Chrome app can include a crude "browser" of sorts within itself using `<webview>`. However, you can't run "proper" extensions in conjunction with that. You can emulate some of the functionality (like content scripts) but not everything. But even then, `<webview>` is not supported in this app-to-mobile translation.

Also, note that the toolchain mentioned in that article **is considered a dead-end**, so it will never be supported:

> The Chrome Apps for Mobile Toolchain ***is no longer being actively developed***. We intend to keep it functional, but do not intend on adding any new features.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Is possible to do a custom app or anything like that that could affect in chrome mobile browser, for example, to highlight parts of the text in a loaded page on chrome mobile browser?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can integrate a WebView (different from Chrome Apps' `<webview>`) into your native Android app and possibly do something similar (using `evaluateJavascript`), but it will be independent of the user's normal browser. You might want to look at Firefox, that has some add-on support for mobile.

Comment: So WebView basically is creating a new browser

Comment: WebView is using Chrome's WebKit core in your app. It's embedding a browser with some limited control over its internals. But that browser does not share any state with "real" Chrome.